# SQL Server 2000 T-SQL: writing to MSMQ?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2000, msmq

Is there a way to write to MSMQ from T-SQL and/or Stored procedure? I am using SQL Server 2000.

Answer (score 3):

Using the OLE Automation procedures: [`sp_OACreate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189763.aspx) and [`sp_OAMethod`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174984.aspx).
See [Posting Message to MSMQ from SQL Server](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/555070).